# A Scala method defined over two equal abstract types

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I'm trying to figure out how I should write a method like Example.baz:

```
class Foo {
  type T
  def send : T
}

class Bar {
  type U
  def receive(u: U)
}

class Example {
  def baz(f: Foo, b: Bar) {
    b.receive(f.send)
  }
}
```

Clearly, this only makes sense in a situation where T = U, and that's my intent. I'm just not sure how to inform the compiler of that intention. I feel like I'm blanking on some incredibly obvious language feature.

Comment: Due to having an abstract method in the concrete classes above, the example does not compile.

Comment: I guess we can use trait instead

Answer (score 7):

A solution is to use Generic instead of internal type:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def send : T
}

trait Bar[T] {
  def receive(t: T)
}

class Example {
  def baz[T](f: Foo[T], b: Bar[T]) {
    b.receive(f.send)
  }
}
```

Or using internal types, as explained in comment by Debilski:

```
class Example {
  def baz[A](f: Foo {type T = A}, b: Bar {type T = A}) {
    b.receive(f.send)
  }
}
```

and if you feel sad because you prefer the use of inner types, be patient, Martin Odersky (and the scala team) is working on it: http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/3d5e2ae8ed6a221f/ff2536f0f0296ec8?#ff2536f0f0296ec8

Comment: I think you meant for `def receive(u: U)` to be `def receive(u: T)`

Comment: Using inner types: `def baz[Ta](f: Foo { type T = Ta }, b: Bar { type T = Ta } )`.

Comment: Oh yes, I still reulct to use this kind of parameters type, but they fit perfectly there, I add them to the solution.